# VHDL read inout port corrupts output signal

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I am triggering a sensor through a *inout* line. After that I am waiting on the sensor to pull *inout* line high but I have troubles reading the *inout* signal back without corrupting my output signal. Writing works, reading not.

Whenever the line

```
elsif state = sensor_answer_0 AND trigger_sensor = '1' then
```

the *ouput_signal* is set to 'X'.

But when I comment *trigger_sensor* out:

```
elsif state = sensor_answer_0 then
```

*output_signal* actually takes the value assigned to it.

I already tried using an internal buffer signal which is read in a seperate process, but that yield the same result.

In the code below I am using *output_signal* also for debugging and I am setting it in each state to see which state is actually executed.
I checked my test bench and there does not seem to be write-write conflict with the *output_signal*. However, I am setting *trigger_sensor*. But only after *trigger_sensor* is already set to 'Z' in my main code.

Why do I see this odd behaviour? Can't I just read an *inout* signal?

I am using 'Quartus II 15.0' and ModelSim for simulation

```
ibrary ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sensor_read is port(
    clk_50: in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;              -- enable sensor read
    trigger_sensor: inout std_logic;    -- 1. trigger sensor, 2. read sensor value
    output_sensor : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) 
);
end sensor_read;


architecture behavior of sensor_read is
--  
    type state_type is (init, trigger_0, trigger_1, sensor_answer_0 );

    signal state : state_type := init;
    signal icnt : std_logic_vector( 18 downto 0 ) := ( others => '0' );  -- counter

----------------------------------------------------------------------  
--- wait for enable
--- trigger sensor
--- wait for sensor to pull trigger line HIGH and assign output
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
begin
    process (clk_50 )
    begin
        if rising_edge( clk_50 ) then
            -- start here
            if state = init AND unsigned( icnt ) = 0 then
                icnt <= ( others => '0' );
                if enable = '1' then                            -- start trigger process
                    state <= trigger_0;
                    trigger_sensor <= '0';
                else
                    state <= init;
                    trigger_sensor <= 'Z';  
                end if; 

            -- TRIGGER SENSOR
            elsif state = trigger_0 AND unsigned( icnt ) = 50 then      
                state <= trigger_1;
                trigger_sensor <= '1';
                output_sensor <= "00000001";    -- debug                                

            elsif state = trigger_1 AND unsigned( icnt ) = 550 then     -- 500 clk cycle
                state <= sensor_answer_0;                   
                icnt <= ( others => '0' );
                trigger_sensor <= 'Z';        -- set trigger to high impedance to let sensor drive line
                output_sensor <= "00001111";  -- debug

            -- WAIT FOR SENSOR TO PULL TRIGGER=HIGH
            -- ERROR HERE -> when trigger_sensor is used in if statement output_sensor becomes xxx
            --               when trigger_sensor = not('1') is commented out, output_sensor is set correctly to "00011111"
            elsif state = sensor_answer_0 AND trigger_sensor = '1' then 
                state <= init;                              
                icnt <= ( others => '0' );                          
                output_sensor <= "00011111";        -- assign final output
            else    
                icnt <= std_logic_vector ( unsigned( icnt ) + 1 );
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process;
end behavior;
```

Edit: Add test bench as requested

```
-- clock generation
process
begin
  clk_50 <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  clk_50 <= '0';
  wait for 10 ns;
end process;

-- input data
process
begin
    enable <= '0'; 
    trigger_sensor <= 'Z';
    wait for 1 ms;

    -- start the meassurement
    enable <= '1';

    -- wait for the trigger signal to be over
    while trigger_sensor /= '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;
    while trigger_sensor = '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;

    -- now send response
    wait for 100 us;
    trigger_sensor <= '1';
    wait for 1 ms;
    trigger_sensor <= '0';
    wait for 10 us;
    trigger_sensor <= 'Z';

    wait;
end process;
```

Comment: You appear to have modeled the bidirectional signal incorrectly. Show your testbench and the values of trigger_sensor.

Comment: why are you using `inout` in the first place? Open-collector logic? VHDL and FPGAs don't really like that. Better to use seperate inputs and outputs: that usually prevents these kind of errors. 
`X` often means that a signal has multiple drivers.

Comment: @user1155120 I added the test bench
@J.H.Bonarius I was not aware of that. I am using an Altera FPGA and I thought `inout` is supported very well in Altera's synthesis tool.

Comment: it is supported. But -like everything- you must know how to use it properly.

Comment: I agree. So far I do not see what is wrong. [According to this](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/v_bidir.html) there not much else to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Once completing a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the  testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sensor_read_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of sensor_read_tb is
    signal clk_50:          std_logic;
    signal enable:          std_logic;
    signal trigger_sensor:  std_logic;
    signal output_sensor:   std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

    --added for visual markers:
    signal waitfor100us:    bit;
    signal waitfor1ms:      bit;
    signal waitfor10us:     bit;
begin
    DUT:
    entity work.sensor_read
        port map (
            clk_50 => clk_50,
            enable => enable,
            trigger_sensor => trigger_sensor,
            output_sensor => output_sensor

        );
    -- clock generation
    process
    begin
      clk_50 <= '1';
      wait for 10 ns;
      clk_50 <= '0';
      wait for 10 ns;
      if now > 2.2 ms then
          wait;
      end if;
    end process;

    -- input data
    process
    begin
        enable <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= 'Z';
        wait for 1 ms;

        -- start the meassurement
        enable <= '1';

        -- wait for the trigger signal to be over
        while trigger_sensor /= '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;
        while trigger_sensor = '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;

        -- now send response
        waitfor100us <= '1';
        wait for 100 us;
        waitfor100us <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= '1';
        waitfor1ms <= '1';
        wait for 1 ms;
        waitfor1ms <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= '0';
        waitfor10us <= '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        waitfor10us <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= 'Z';

        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

We see the problem:

[image: enter sensor_read_tb.png]

A couple of signals were added in the testbench to mark your delays. They can easily be discarded. The simulator used won't output variables to a waveform.
Your not operating the bidirection sensor signal correctly.

So how is it supposed to operate?

In the first dozen or so Google hits, the original [Single line multiplexing system for sensors and actuators](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/4311986.pdf) patent shows up, granted in 1982 as United States Patent 4,311,986.

While the patent is long expired it 'teaches' the invention.

There's also the [MAX6575L/H](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6575-MAX6575L.pdf) datasheet that tell us you want to operate the counter from the time the FPGA drops trigger_sensor until the time the sensor drops trigger sensor again.

The way this works is the FPGA will drop trigger_sensor for a fixed interval signalling any sensors or actuators on the single wire bus to start. Up to 8 devices can share a bus using multipliers to scale a time according to two input pins, with two delay families (the H and L suffixes).

For a single sensor it will respond in it's time window by dropping trigger sensor again for a fixed period signalling a pulse width modulation encoded value (typically for a temperature).

An actuator would be operated by the host end (an FPGA in this case by dropping the trigger sensor line again sending a pulse width encoded data value to the the actuator.

The counter can be big enough to restart by rolling over whenever no sensor answers restarting the sampling interval.
The VHDL model we have here only reads sensors.

So back to what's wrong with the bidirectional signal.

It should be modeled as an open collector with two drivers and a pullup. The statemachine may be a bit overkill for a single sensor but can be made to work.

The trick here is that neither end drives a '1' onto the wire, only a '0' or a 'Z' (high impedence). The pullup will a 'Z' to an 'H' and represents a resistor (the datasheet shows a 10K ohm resistor).

To read a one takes filtering to '0' or '1' values and the std_logic_1164 package has a function TO_01 to do that with an added input with a default value that maps meta-values to '0'. For our purposes using an open collector model we want the function to map meta-values to '1'.

For cases where you're not using TO-01 which is not available in earlier revisions of the std_logic_1164 package it's been included. All the changes made to your VHDL source have been annotated:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sensor_read is
    port (
        clk_50:         in  std_logic;
        enable:         in  std_logic;      -- enable sensor read
        trigger_sensor: inout std_logic;    -- 1. trigger sensor, 2. read sensor value
        output_sensor:  out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity sensor_read;


architecture behavior of sensor_read is

    type state_type is (init, trigger_0, trigger_1, sensor_answer_0);
    signal state:  state_type := init;
    signal icnt:  std_logic_vector( 18 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    -- for VHDL revisions prior to -2008:
    function TO_01 (s: STD_ULOGIC; xmap: std_ulogic := '0') return std_ulogic is
    begin
        case s is
            when '0' | 'L' => 
                return '0';
            when '1' | 'H' => 
                return '1';
            when others    => 
                return xmap;
        end case;
    end function TO_01;
begin
    process (clk_50)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_50) then
            if state = init AND unsigned(icnt) = 0 then
                icnt <= ( others => '0' );
                if enable = '1' then
                    state <= trigger_0;
                    trigger_sensor <= '0';
                else
                    state <= init;
                    trigger_sensor <= 'Z';
                end if;
            elsif state = trigger_0 AND unsigned(icnt) = 50 then
                state <= trigger_1;
                trigger_sensor <= 'Z'; -- WAS '1';
                output_sensor <= "00000001";

            elsif state = trigger_1 AND unsigned(icnt) = 550 then
                state <= sensor_answer_0;
                icnt <= (others => '0');
                trigger_sensor <= 'Z';
                output_sensor <= "00001111";
            elsif state = sensor_answer_0 AND 
                   TO_01(trigger_sensor, xmap => '1') = '1' then -- CHANGED
                state <= init;
                icnt <= ( others => '0' );
                output_sensor <= "00011111";
            else
                icnt <= std_logic_vector (unsigned(icnt) + 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behavior;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sensor_read_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of sensor_read_tb is
    signal clk_50:          std_logic;
    signal enable:          std_logic;
    signal trigger_sensor:  std_logic;
    signal output_sensor:   std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

    --added for visual markers:
    signal waitfor100us:    bit;
    signal waitfor1ms:      bit;
    signal waitfor10us:     bit;
    -- for VHDL revisions prior to -2008:
    function TO_01 (s: STD_ULOGIC; xmap: std_ulogic := '0') return std_ulogic is
    begin
        case s is
            when '0' | 'L' => 
                return '0';
            when '1' | 'H' => 
                return '1';
            when others    => 
                return xmap;
        end case;
    end function TO_01;
begin
    DUT:
    entity work.sensor_read
        port map (
            clk_50 => clk_50,
            enable => enable,
            trigger_sensor => trigger_sensor,
            output_sensor => output_sensor

        );
    -- clock generation
    process
    begin
      clk_50 <= '1';
      wait for 10 ns;
      clk_50 <= '0';
      wait for 10 ns;
      if now > 2.2 ms then
          wait;
      end if;
    end process;

    -- input data
    process
    begin
        enable <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= 'Z';
        wait for 1 ms;

        -- start the meassurement
        enable <= '1';

        -- wait for the trigger signal to be over
        while TO_01(trigger_sensor, '1') /= '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;
        while TO_01(trigger_sensor, '1')  = '1' loop wait for 1 us; end loop;

        -- now send response
        waitfor100us <= '1';
        wait for 100 us;
        waitfor100us <= '0';
        -- trigger_sensor <= '1';
        trigger_sensor <= 'Z';  -- WAS '1';
        waitfor1ms <= '1';
        wait for 1 ms;
        waitfor1ms <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= '0';
        waitfor10us <= '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        waitfor10us <= '0';
        trigger_sensor <= 'Z';

        wait;
    end process;
PULLUP:                       -- ADDED
    trigger_sensor <= 'H';    -- PULLUP
end architecture;
```

And this gives us signal waveform that works:

[image: sensor_read1.png]

Because the sensor driving trigger_sensor low is asynchronous you might consider meta-stability filtering to the state machine on trigger_sensor.

If you examine a waveform displaying after the time showing the waitfor10us pulse you'll see the testbench doesn't match the count interval for the sensor_read design unit. There may be some tinkering needed. Also note the counter is running after the testbench signals a value. There needs to be a bit of tinkering here.